# Issue in special character encoding in ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, utf-8

I am having a json file which has special characters in it. But when I make ajax call to get that file, in success callback some characters are converted to `�`. I have set content-type as:

> application/json;charset=UTF-8.

Below is `myfile.json` content and `ajax` call:

```
{
    "image": "images/item.jpg",
    "text": "there’re software products® "
}

$.ajax({
    async:false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "JSON/myfile.json",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    success: function (data) {
        arrayobj = data;
    }
});
```

I tried setting encoding of json file as `UTF-8` from `ANSI` but still `�` appear.

Comment: Your JSON file is not encoded correctly. That's why we can't see the character on this page

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for your response  I have set json file encoding as UTF-8 from Notepad++ but still get same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the character encoding of your file. Try to convert your `myfile.json` to UTF-8 if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can value of contentType replace with

```
contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: Thanks Yasemin , I have set this but still issue is same